The archive did not include a dSYM for the React Native with the UUIDs
For React native Trying to publish an app on the Apple app store. But after building the archive, when I try to distribute or validate the app, Xcode keeps me showing
The archive did not include a dSYM for the hermes.framework with the UUIDs . Ensure that the archive's dSYM folder includes a DWARF file for hermes.framework with the expected UUIDs.
How can I overcome this?

did you find a solution?

you can't download the dSYM directly for that you need to follow these steps.

Identify your react-native version
Download the Hermes release for your React Native version. React Native provides Hermes releases, which you can find at this Maven repository:


https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native-artifacts/


Locate the version matching your React Native version
For example, if you're using React Native 0.72.10,



Select the version and download the corresponding release: react-native-artifacts-0.72.10-hermes-ios-release.tar.gz



Extract the downloaded .tar.gz file to your machine. Navigate to the extracted directory:

react-native-artifacts-0.72.10-hermes-ios-release/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64


Run the following command to generate the .dSYM file for the Hermes framework:

dsymutil hermes.framework/hermes -o hermes.framework.dSYM


Use the generated .dSYM file to upload it to your crash reporting tool like Sentry or Firebase Crashlytics.


upload it where?

To your crash reporting tool, like:
Sentry - https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/apple/dsym/
Firebase Crashlytics - https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios
